# What are the drawback if I use 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.1.1 in my host file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, localhost

Ubuntu default host file is something like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   myhostname
```

Will there be any drawback if I change to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost myhostname
```

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.0/8 (127.*.*.*) will all point to your local machine, regardless which address you use. The only thing that matters is that the hostname provided in `/etc/hostname` resolves to an IP address, but you can use any IP address on your computer you like. For more details read this: [127.0.1.1 ? Ubuntu / Debian](http://www.leonardoborda.com/blog/127-0-1-1-ubuntu-debian/)

However, next time you might want to Google a bit before posting your question.